# Using Regular Expressions for Search/Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a String like this `item width200height300`. The values of width an height may be different. Like this
`item width100height100` or item `width50height300`.

How can you search and replace `widthxxxheightxxx` with Regular Expressions?

Comment: You should read a little bit about Regex, that's a really easy one and you can figure out by yourself. If you don't try anything you want us to do the work for you and that's not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function replacer(match, p1, p2){
  // do something with p1 or p2
  return "item width"+p1+"heigth"+p2;
};
newString = "item width50height300".replace(/width(\d+)height(\d+)/, replacer);
console.log(newString);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
/width\d+height\d+/
```